# How do I make Kubernetes evict a pod that has not been ready for a period of time?

Tags: kubernetes

I have readiness probes configured on several pods (which are members of deployment-managed replica sets). They work as expected -- readiness is required as part of the deployment's rollout strategy, and if a healthy pod becomes NotReady, the associated Service will remove it from the pool of endpoints until it becomes Ready again.

Furthermore, I have external health checking (using Sensu) that alerts me when a pod becomes NotReady.

Sometimes, a pod will report NotReady for an extended period of time, showing no sign of recovery. I would like to configure things such that, if a pod stays in NotReady for an extended period of time, it gets evicted from the node and rescheduled elsewhere. I'll settle for a mechanism that simply kills the container (leading it to be restarted in the same pod), but what I really want is for the pod to be evicted and rescheduled.

I can't seem to find anything that does this. Does it exist? Most of my searching turns up things about evicting pods from NotReady *nodes*, which is not what I'm looking for at all.

If this doesn't exist, why? Is there some other mechanism I should be using to accomplish something equivalent?

EDIT: I should have specified that I also have liveness probes configured and working the way I want. In the scenario I’m talking about, the pods are “alive.” My liveness probe is configured to detect more severe failures and restart aggressively, and is working as desired.

I’m really looking for the ability to evict based on a pod being live but not ready for an extended period of time.

I guess what I really want is the ability to configure an arbitrary number of probes, each with different expectations it checks for, and each with different actions it will take if a certain failure threshold is reached. As it is now, liveness failures have only one method of recourse (restart the container), and readiness failures also have just one (just wait). I want to be able to configure any action.

Comment: Does the Deployment have liveness probe configured wih `restartPolicy` of Always or OnFailure?

Comment: @apisim the podSpec in the deployment specifies both liveness and readiness probes. Restart policy is unspecified; the default is Always. But that only matters if the pod has exited or is failing its liveness probe, which isn’t the scenario I’m asking about.

Comment: Sorry, I meant if the _container_ has exited. I’ve edited my question to clarify what I’m asking for.

Comment: Perhaps a way to achieve what you want is to combine in the liveness probe the check for "alive" with the check for "ready" - that will cause a pod to be evicted when it is not ready for an extended period of time assuming the check for "alive" succeeds and the check (not the probe) for "ready" fails. Not knowing enough about the checks the probes execute (i.e. HTTP GET, command/script, TCP socket...)...a suggestion could be to use a script to do that and if it's simple enough it doesn't have to be baked into the image but could be placed in the `livenessProbe.exec.command`.

Comment: I could do that, but because I can only set one set of criteria for it, it would require increasing the tolerance of the liveness check such that it would not aggressively restart the container when it was truly dead. I'd prefer to keep that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never got a great answer to this question, but judging by the Popular Question badge I just got, other people are wondering the same thing, and no great solutions have come to the platform in the meantime. So, four years later I'm going to come back and share some things I've learned.

[@mario's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58084138/535401) is decent. I don't love it, because configuring the desired behavior involves three separate systems, and that undermines the cohesiveness of the pod's declarative configuration.

I said I'd settle for killing the container and having it restart, and that can be done via a more sophisticated liveness endpoint which keeps track of non-readiness and reports (questionably) that it is not alive. Paired with [Descheduler](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/descheduler)'s [`RemovePodsHavingTooManyRestarts`](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/descheduler?tab=readme-ov-file#removepodshavingtoomanyrestarts), that could even support eventual eviction from the node. This involves a tiny, trivial bit of statefulness in the container, which I think can be tolerated. Any time the readiness endpoint is called, update an in-memory timestamp of when the pod was last ready. Any time the liveness endpoint is called, check that timestamp to see if its age exceeds a certain threshold.

There's probably a version of the above which uses a sidecar such that the behavior can be shared across many pods. I'm not going to take the time to design that one right now.

Another approach would be to add a strategy plugin to [Descheduler](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/descheduler) which detects pods in this state. I'd add a metadata to the pod spec which specifies that this behavior is desired and sets the threshold for how much non-ready time we'll tolerate, and then I'd use the pod's events to determine how long it had been non-ready.

Descheduler doesn't support custom strategies, so you'd either have to fork the repo and maintain your own custom version, or submit a PR and wait/hope for it to get merged and released. Neither of these are likely to be ideal for you, so I think I'd probably go with the fancy liveness probe/sidecar option described above, paired with regular Descheduler.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to use for that purpose **Prometheus** metrics and create an **alert** like [here](https://github.com/kubernetes-monitoring/kubernetes-mixin/blob/master/runbook.md#alert-name-kubepodnotready). Based on that you can configure a webhook in [alertmanager](https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/alertmanager/#alertmanager), which will react properly ( action: kill POD ) and the Pod will be then recreated by the scheduler.

Comment: Four years later, this is the only answer I ever got that was any good for my desired purpose. It leaves a bit to be desired (I was hoping for built-in functionality), and in the spirit of SO it would be great if it included more details, but none of the other answers even came close. An upvote for you, sir.

Answer (score 0):

As of Kubernetes v1.15, you might want to use a combination of readiness probe and liveness probe to achieve the outcome that you want . See [configure liveness and readiness probes.](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes/)

A new feature to start the liveness probe after the pod is ready is likely to be introduced in v1.16. There will be a new probe called [startupProbe](https://github.com/kubernetes/website/pull/15714) that can handle this in a more intuitive manner.

Comment: This is not what I’m looking for. I clarified my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure HTTP liveness probe or TCP liveness probe with periodSeconds  depends on the type of the container images.

```
    livenessProbe:
       .....
       initialDelaySeconds: 3
       periodSeconds: 5  [ This field specifies that kubelet should perform liveness probe every 3 seconds. ]
```

Comment: This is not what I’m looking for. I’ve clarified my question.